# Ejecutar código SQL que genera una vista

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net

Tengo el siguiente código **SQL** que crea una vista y funciona perfectamente desde el Server Management Studio:

```
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[view_solicitud] AS
(SELECT *,  
    ISNULL(
        CASE  WHEN DATEPART(hour,HORAENTRADA) < 10 THEN '0' + CAST(DATEPART(hour,HORAENTRADA) AS NVARCHAR(2))
            WHEN DATEPART(hour,HORAENTRADA) > 9 THEN CAST(DATEPART(hour,HORAENTRADA) AS NVARCHAR(2))
        END
        + ':' +
        CASE  WHEN DATEPART(minute,HORAENTRADA) < 10 THEN '0' + CAST(DATEPART(minute,HORAENTRADA) AS NVARCHAR(2))
            WHEN DATEPART(minute,HORAENTRADA) > 9 THEN CAST(DATEPART(minute,HORAENTRADA) AS NVARCHAR(2))
        END
    ,'') AS HORAENTRADA_STR,
    ISNULL(
        CASE  WHEN DATEPART(hour,HORASALIDA) < 10 THEN '0' + CAST(DATEPART(hour,HORASALIDA) AS NVARCHAR(2))
            WHEN DATEPART(hour,HORASALIDA) > 9 THEN CAST(DATEPART(hour,HORASALIDA) AS NVARCHAR(2))
        END
        + ':' +
        CASE  WHEN DATEPART(minute,HORASALIDA) < 10 THEN '0' + CAST(DATEPART(minute,HORASALIDA) AS NVARCHAR(2))
            WHEN DATEPART(minute,HORASALIDA) > 9 THEN CAST(DATEPART(minute,HORASALIDA) AS NVARCHAR(2))
        END
     ,'') AS HORASALIDA_STR
FROM solicitud)
```

Ahora estoy haciendo un programa en **C#** que toma de un txt mi Script para crear la base de datos, y ejecuta sin problema, pero cuando al txt, le añado el código que crea la vista, me tira error al crear la base de datos.

Lo estoy ejecutando de la siguiente forma:

```
    try
    {
        //Creamos nueva base de datos
        script_base = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "crear_base.txt");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(script_base, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path + "log_instalacion.txt", true))
        {
            outputFile.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
        estatus_conexion = "Error de conexión. " + ex.Message;
        throw new InstallException("Error al crear la base de datos.");
    }
```

> CREATE VIEW must be first statement in a batch

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

He intentado el separador de Lotes **GO** sin obtener resultados satisfactorios, me sigue tirando el mismo error.

¿Alguna parte del código de la vista puede estar causando error o a que se podría deber?

Comment: ¿Que error te muestra cuando ejecutas el valor de la variable `script_base`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Les comento que investigando un poco, al parecer en cuanto se refiere a Vistas y Procedimientos, estos códigos deben de ir solos, es decir ser la única linea en mi script, la solución fue crear un txt donde solo pongo el código de la creación de tablas, y otro que se ejecute seguidamente que contenga únicamente el código de la vista, y si tuviera más vistas, tendría que tener un txt por cada una.

Referencia:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465777/why-create-view-must-be-first-statement-in-a-batch

Teniendo lo anterior me quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
        try
        {
            //Creamos nueva base de datos
            script_base = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "crear_base.txt");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(script_base, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path + "log_instalacion.txt", true))
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            estatus_conexion = "Error de conexión. " + ex.Message;
            throw new InstallException("Error al crear la base de datos."+ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            script_base = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "crear_vista.txt");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(script_base, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path + "log_instalacion.txt", true))
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            estatus_conexion = "Error de conexión. " + ex.Message;
            throw new InstallException("Error al crear vistas" + ex.Message);
        }
```

Donde tengo en un txt **crear_base.txt** el Script que crea mi base, y después de que se ejecuta, ejecuto un segundo txt **crear_vista.txt** donde se encuentra únicamente el Script que crea la vista.

Comment: No, no es necesario tener un archivo por separado para cada función, vista o procedimiento. Utiliza el separador de lotes GO al finalizar cada rutina de creación: CREATE VIEW <> AS (...); GO CREATE PROCEDURE <> ...; GO

Comment: M.Gress si esto intenta ser una respuesta, tiene que tener la calidad suficietne explicada en [answer]

Comment: Nos alegra mucho que hayas encontra una solución por tu cuenta y que quieras compartirla con nosotros. Yo creo que con un ejemplo quedaria muche mejor explicado, considera a los futuros usuarios que tengan este problema.

Comment: He modificado mi respuesta tratando de ser más claro. :)

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate que el script de creación de la vista se ejecuta posterior a la creación de la tabla 'solicitud'.

Por otro lado, podrías reducir el código de la vista de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[view_solicitud] 
AS
SELECT 
    *,  
    FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, HORAENTRADA), 'HH:mm') AS HORAENTRADA_STR,
    FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, HORASALIDA), 'HH:mm') AS HORASALIDA_STR
FROM solicitud;
```

Comment: Gracias, pero ya lo he solucionado.